# copy color theme from data validation cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, data-validation

So I'm using data validations alot.

for better organization I create tab called `setup` and I put my list of possible options there

let's say I want to categorize my credit card expenses

so I'll put a possible categories list in the `setup` tab as following:

[image]

now in the other tab: `credit card expenses`, I'll set data validation rule as such:
[image]

(*) I usually select longer list than the existing one so I can easily add more later and it will already be defined in the list (for this example I can add more in cells `L8:L17`)

Now, to make things more readable I like to add colors,
So I want that the following color theme will be applied in my credit card expenses:

[image]

Now, as far as I know, if I want to set such color theme, for N categories,

I need to set N different conditional formatting rules stating:

if X=="supermarket" => color=yellow

if X=="entertainment" => color=purple

...

etc..

Now, as you can now see, if N is very big, this process gets annoying,
especially if I have multiple tabs such as `credit card expenses` and I need to set those rules to each of them..
Also if I want to change those colors later, I'll need to update those rules everywhere I did so.

Also, cutting and pasting cells kinda ruins conditional formatting rules so I don't quite like them..

**so my question is:**

> Can I simply color up the cells in my `setup` tab and somehow set the
> data validation rule to copy the color with it from the range list?

Comment: No such option with Conditional formatting, the way out is to make a script.

Comment: **"so my question is:"** It would have been useful to say this in the first few sentences.